# Connect to a WCF service (.svc) via a proxy (with username / password)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I've created a WCF service. I call it like this:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient ();
client.MyMethod();
```

So far so good on my machine.

Now I've deployed it in our DMZ (whatever that is), and I can call it via an outside URL (so the request from my machine goes out to the Internet and then goes to our datacenter).

But, we connect via a proxy to the Internet. I am not sure how that works, but I have to enter a proxy server in the connections, LAN settings section of Internet Explorer if I want to visit the Stack Overflow site.

When I don't change the code, I get this error:

> The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (407) Proxy
>   Authentication Required ( The ISA
>   Server requires authorization to
>   fulfill the request. Access to the Web
>   Proxy filter is denied.  ).

After googling, I found this code, but it leaves me with the same error.

```
  var b = client.Endpoint.Binding as System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding;
            b.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://OURADDRESS.intern:8080");     
            b.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;     
            b.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"DOMAIN\USERNAME";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myverysecretpassword";
```

Comment: Can you try with UseDefaultWebProxy = true and dont set the ClientCredentials. This should use the proxy settings from IE.

Comment: that gave me the same exception

Comment: You should start by asking your admin what type of authentication your proxy expects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such a case, using the default proxy should be enough:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
  ...
</configuration>
```

In your binding, you must only ensure using the default proxy (should be enabled by default):

```
b.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
```

In case of manually setting credentials, I believe that your proxy expect Windows credentials and because of that this should be used:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = @"DOMAIN\USERNAME";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myverysecretpassword";
```

Comment: error: The caller was not authenticated by the service. (without the credentials)

Comment: error: The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed. (WITH the credentials)

Comment: fillder says: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.